# To display page breadcrumb dynamically different for each page through header.php

Tags: php, html

I'm beginner with php, so I guess this will sound a dumb question for most people. I want to add a custom breadcrumb for each page dynamically through `header.php` file, and want to pass the page name through particular page.

I tried to do this but it is giving an error.

```
<div class="page-title">
    <div class="auto-container">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pull-left">
                <h1>
                    <?php echo $pagetitle ?>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pull-right text-right path">
                <a href="#">Home</a>&ensp;
                <span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>&ensp;
                <a href="#"><?php echo $page->title ?></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And passed `$title="page title "` in specific pages.

Please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using `$pagetitle` and `$page->title` in your code, but you're passing `$title` in your pages.

You should just use `<?php echo $title; ?>`, or its short form: `<?= $title ?>`